# How to run WildFly with standalone-full.xml from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm trying to run Wildfly 8.0 from Intellij IDEA. When starting WildFly through commmand-line I can use the `-c standalone-full.xml` parameter to use the `standalone-full.xml` configuration file. How can I specify this when running WildFly from Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In my opinion switch `-c standalone-full.xml` is not a `VM Option` so I will post a little bit different solution:
In the Run/Debug configuration for your server in the tab `Startup/Connection` you have the ability to set `Startup script:` On the end of line there is checkbox `Use default`. Please unselect it and paste on the end of the input `-c standalone-full.xml`

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer. As mentioned, this is not VM Options.

Comment: Important: it seems that IntelliJ always reads ports from standalone.xml, so if you ports differ, you will be unable to deploy.

Comment: The answer from @MikeHoldsworth has the advantage that can you specify your standalone configuration once in the `VM options:`. When using the `Startup script:`, you have to do it three times: for `Run`, `Debug` and `Coverage`.

Comment: This doesnt work on intellij 2017.1.3 and wildfly 10

Comment: @Krzysztof Miksa Thanks a ton.. saved my day

Answer (score 39):

Adding `-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml` to VM_OPTIONS is the equivalent of running `standalone -c standalone-full.xml` from a shell

Answer (score 9):

As said by Mike Holdsworth `-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml` works perfectly.
But there is another advantage over the `-c standalone-full.xml` method.

When you rename your `standalone.xml` file to create custom configuration files for multiple environments. Like `env1.xml`, `env2.xml`, etc.
If you use `-c env1.xml`, Intellij will give you the following message:

> Error: HTTP management port configuration not found.

So you have to put a basic `standalone.xml` who will be overriden at the startup by the one you give with the `-c` option.

The `-Djboss.server.default.config=env1.xml` will prevent it.

Comment: Brilliant. I used to have complete different 'standalone' directories for each config but adjusting my scripts to point to the currently correct dir was annoying. With your method I just have one dir with multiple configs!

Comment: Great addition. Instead of creating a new answer, it would be nice to append this to the either @mike-holdsworth 's answer, or to the accepted one.

Comment: I tried this method but it led to another problem: adding things to VM_OPTIONS will set the JAVA_OPTS and if the JAVA_OPTS is not empty, then the standalone.conf is totally skipped (and I get OOMEs because no memory allocation settings are added)... is there a simple way (= without changing to much files) to use an alternate config file AND have the standalone.conf correctly processed?

Answer (score 2):

Look out for different startup scripts for "Run" and "Debug" in Intellij IDEA. If you don't uncheck "Use default" in both of them then you can end up with two different profiles on "Run" and "Debug". It is easy to forget and annoying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it by default w/o passing any command line parameters than go
to standalone.(bat|sh)

Append to the **SERVER_OPTS** variable: --server-config=standalone-full.xml

At least now you'll run it in full mode from any place (ide, service, command line)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a cross-platform team and we share our run configs.  Modifying the startup script could cause problems (other teammate's paths and startup scripts are different), so my solution was:

- Made a backup of standalone.xml
- Renamed standalone-full.xml to standalone.xml

This doesn't answer the OP's question directly, but may be helpful for folks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Run/Debug configuration for your server you have the ability to set `VM options`. You can put your switch in there. You may have problems however with jboss identifying the correct path for the file, so you may have to play with that a little bit before it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
Run -> Edit configurations -> Click '+' in the top left corner -> JBoss Server -> Local
```

There you can configure your JBoss instance and set VM options and so on.